# Understanding typeallias CellProvider

Tags: ios, swift

Exploring documentation i find following syntax:

```
public typealias CellProvider = (UICollectionView, IndexPath, ItemIdentifierType) -> UICollectionViewCell?
```

I'm not sure what type is it, how to create that CellProvider? Is that a simple closure? How to use it, and how to pass it? Can someone please provide a reference link? That look weird for me to understand,

Comment: Example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p466collectionViewFlowLayout3Diffable/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/ViewController.swift#L32 (see line 32 if you don't scroll there automatically)

Comment: It’s not named well. Because it’s a closure, it’s not a noun. `ProvideCell` would be more accurate.

Comment: @Jessy That's a matter of opinion; I disagree on several grounds. Simply put, this function does a job: it provides a cell. It is indeed a cell provider. French and Spanish can behave as you suggest (parapluie, parabrisas) but English does not; in English, names of things are nouns, not verbs (except some archisms).

Comment: You are overcomplicating the logic. In Swift, you take a lowerCamelCase thing, and to get its type, you capitalize the name. If this were a method, it would be named `provideCell`. If you don't botch the naming, as `CellProvider` does, this will result in neologisms that are deverbal nouns.

Comment: @Jessy Yes, indeed, in fact in the example in my answer, my method is called `makeCell`. So what is it? It's a CellMaker.

Comment: No, that’s a `MakeCell`. A `CellMaker` would be a type with a `makeCell` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That describes the function (usually an anonymous function in "trailing closure" position) that is provided to the initializer of a diffable data source for a collection view. Takes three parameters and returns a cell.

Example from my own code:

```
self.datasource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String,String>(collectionView:self.collectionView) { cv,ip,s in
    return self.makeCell(cv,ip,s)
}
```

where `makeCell` is basically the same as what `cellForItemAt` used to do.